flexWrap causing height issues
In my react-native app, when I set flexWrap to the parent, the height remains as not having the children wrapped.
Code:
styles: {
    backgroundColor: "red", columnGap: 10, flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap", height: "auto",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly", marginBottom: 0, marginTop: 5,
    minHeight: Dimensions.get("window").height, overflow: "visible", rowGap: 10
}

...

<View style={styles}>
  {...map(....)}

